# Adjusting object position on header if another object grows?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

[image]

So I have that in my reports header, I set the Customer object to grow in case it needs to occupy 2 lines. I adjusted the Address downwards as seen on the image, my problem is if the customer only occupies 1 line then i'll have this weird blank space between customer and address. What can I do so I don't have that blank space if the Customer object only needs 1 line.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what I ended up doing is using a formula and concatenated the 2 objects. As for the formatting I set the concatenated object to be read as HTML and formatted the 2 objects differently using HTML tags in the formula.